# Concise multi-line substring extraction

Tags: android, perl

Ok, some shell magic I know, but my head would not parse required `sed` complications at this time of the day so I tried `perl`. Now haha, what a variable space explosion... but well got around it somehow, only took me an hour. S0Oo. Abusing my shell for REPL to try extracting names and versions from the android installed packages list..

```
dumpsys package packages > dump
( set -xv; while perl -ne "$(rlwrap cat)" < dump; do eval printf "=%.s" {1..$(tput cols)}; echo; done; )
```

I figured this to work:

```
 dumpsys package packages|perl -ne 'if (/Package \[(.*)\]/g) {print "$1 -- "}; if (/versionName=(.*)/g) {print "$1\n"}'|sort
```

How can this be shortened? `dumpsys` output looks like this:

```
  Package [org.fdroid.fdroid.privileged] (64fb46e0):
    userId=10022 gids=[]
    pkg=Package{6501d0a8 org.fdroid.fdroid.privileged}
    codePath=/system/priv-app/FDroidPrivileged.apk
    resourcePath=/system/priv-app/FDroidPrivileged.apk
    nativeLibraryPath=/data/app-lib/FDroidPrivileged
    versionCode=1050 targetSdk=22
    versionName=0.1
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{64f94838 org.fdroid.fdroid.privileged}
    flags=[ HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ]
    dataDir=null
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2016-02-25 08:36:51
    firstInstallTime=2016-02-25 08:36:51
    lastUpdateTime=2016-02-25 08:36:51
    signatures=PackageSignatures{64fb4818 []}
    permissionsFixed=false haveGids=false installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ SYSTEM PRIVILEGED ]
    User 0:  installed=true blocked=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0
    grantedPermissions:
      android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
      android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES
  Package [ds.cpuoverlay] (64f98b70):
    userId=10048 gids=[3003, 1028, 1015, 1023]
    pkg=Package{64fd32a8 ds.cpuoverlay}
    codePath=/data/app/ds.cpuoverlay-1.apk
    resourcePath=/data/app/ds.cpuoverlay-1.apk
    nativeLibraryPath=/data/app-lib/ds.cpuoverlay-1
    versionCode=83 targetSdk=22
    versionName=5.7.0
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{6514bcb0 ds.cpuoverlay}
    flags=[ HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    dataDir=/data/data/ds.cpuoverlay
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2017-06-21 10:19:53
    firstInstallTime=2017-02-05 17:28:29
    lastUpdateTime=2017-06-21 10:19:55
    signatures=PackageSignatures{64f98c38 [64f999e8]}
    permissionsFixed=true haveGids=true installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    User 0:  installed=true blocked=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You do need two matches on long-ish phrases, but it can be simplified (and shortened) a bit

```
dumpsys package packages | perl -nE'
    /^\s*Package \[(.*)\]/ && print "$1 -- "; /^\s*versionName=(.*)/ && say $1
' | sort
```

with output

```
ds.cpuoverlay -- 5.7.0
org.fdroid.fdroid.privileged -- 0.1
```

I tested with your posted input in a text file that I fed into  `perl -nE '...' input.txt | sort`